# Adding line break into a txt file - Java

Tags: java, sql

This is probably a really simple question but im just learning Java and need help. I have a line of sql table writing to txt file but its not adding a linebreak after each append. Its just appending them all together as one word. How do i insert a linebreak after each append? Column is an address so 1 address per line.

```
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer();
TableModel tModel = table.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < tModel.getRowCount(); i++) {

    Object cellValue = tModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
    // ... continue to read each cell in a row
    fileContent.append(cellValue);

    // ... continue to append each cell value
}

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("D://properties1.txt"));
fileWriter.write(fileContent.toString());

fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: Append a `"\n"` at each iteration.

Comment: Strange.  fileContent.append(cellValue + "\n \n \n"); just adds 3 spaces rather than any line breaks.

Comment: Formats OK in Wordpad but how do i make it linebreak in notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as 
fileContent.append(cellValue + "\n");

Comment: Strange. Each \n i add it just adds a space rather than a linebreak.

Comment: Strange.  fileContent.append(cellValue + "\n \n \n"); just adds 3 spaces rather than any line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

just before the end of the loop add `fileContent.append("\n");`

Answer (score 0):

use the new line char, \n.

where you have this                  `fileContent.append(cellValue);`

should be                  `fileContent.append(cellValue+"\n");`

Answer (score 0):

For windows applications like notepad, you need to use a carriage return followed by a new line.

```
fileContent.append("\r\n");
```